# How do I find the Dell controller and pdisk number given a serial number?

Tags: centos, hardware, dell-perc, dell-openmanage

I need to blink a drive that I found out had SMART errors using smartmontools. I have `omconfig` installed and [it looks like it can be used for blinking LEDs](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/36723/Dell-Command-Line-Interface.html?page=168), but I don't know how to find the controller and pdisk number it needs

As an alternative, I tried looking for `/locate` files in `/sys` but they corresponded to controller slots, not the drive letters.

I am using CentOS 7 on a Dell PowerEdge R730.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try using `ledctl` from the `ledmon` package. It is quite simple to use:

Locate a drive:

```sh
ledctl locate=/dev/sda
```

Stop locating a drive:

```sh
ledctl locate_off=/dev/sda
```

If this doesn't work, on Dell systems the `omreport` tool can be useful for finding drives. I wrote the following script for taking a serial number of a drive (like you can get with `smartctl`) and returning the controller and pdisk id:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
serialnumber=$1
controllers=$(omreport storage controller | grep '^ID' | awk '{print $3}')
for controller in $controllers; do
    id=$(omreport storage pdisk controller=$controller | grep --before 25 $serialnumber | grep '^ID' | awk '{print $3}')
    if [ ! -z "$id" ]; then echo "controller=$controller pdisk=$id"; fi
done;
```

It can be used like so:

```
[root@computer ~]# ./get_pdisk_from_serial.sh BTHC711202VV1P6PGN
controller=0 pdisk=0:0:4
```